# Make wchar_t upper case with LCMapString API

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, locale

I'm curious about the [LCMapString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318700(v=vs.85).aspx) API for a Windows app. My goal is to capitalize a single `wchar_t` (or 2-byte character.) Am I safe to assume that it will always map it to a single `wchar_t`?

Or this:

```
wchar_t c1 = input_character;   //Say, L'd';
wchar_t c2 = 0;
if(LCMapString(LOCALE_INVARIANT, LCMAP_UPPERCASE, &c1, 1, &c2, 1))
{
    //Success, capitalized result is in `c2`
}
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that all single lowercase `wchar_t` values can map to a single uppercase `wchar_t`. The German `ß` (U+00DF LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S) is a common example of this. Depending on the context in which it is used, on Unicode compliance, etc, it can sometimes map to `SS` (2 U+0053 LATIN CAPITAL S) or to `ẞ` (U+1E9E LATIN CAPITAL LETTER SHARP S).  And not all Unicode characters can be represented in a single `wchar_t` to begin with.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thank you. So I'm assuming that this article is wrong then, hah? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greggm/archive/2005/09/21/472453.aspx

Comment: The blog is about comparing file names, not strings in general.

Comment: @BoPersson: NTFS stores filenames as sequences of UTF-16 code units. It makes no restrictions on valid code units (with the exception of 0x0000). In fact, it doesn't even validate, whether surrogate pairs consist of valid code units. As such, comparing filenames is the more general case. Of course, the OS does place restrictions on what is a valid filename. With the exception of certain characters in the ASCII range, all Unicode code points are allowed, so this doesn't introduce any restrictions over general strings in the context of the question.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Maybe you should make your comment into an answer.